# Сделать кнопку неактивной при входе пользователя через форму Логина

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется две формы: основная и форма авторизации пользователя. При входе (когда введён верный логин/пароль) идёт переход на главную форму и я хочу сделать так,чтобы некоторая кнопка стала неактивной после входа. Пробовал уже много вариантов и кнопка так и остаётся активной. Помогите, пожалуйста!

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (textBox1.Text == "user" && textBox2.Text == "1234")
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

            MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
            mainForm.button13.Enabled = false;
        }

        else if (textBox1.Text == "manager" && textBox2.Text == "4321")
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }

        else
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort; 
        this.Close(); 
    }
```

Comment: А как Вы пробовали?.. можете привести код попытки?

Comment: не знаю насколько большой код данных форм у Вас, но вполне возможно что будет полезно привести ту часть кода, которая имеет отношение к вопросу

Comment: Справка: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

попробуй использовать Visible = false

Comment: Это не ответ, а комментарий (по делу). По правилам SO, Вам осталось лишь заработать репутацию, что иметь возможность комментировать вопросы :).

Comment: Если уж на то пошло, то нужно использовать `Enabled = false;`. В вопросе речь идет о неактивной кнопке, а не о невидимой.